# How to create flowdocument table of contents

Tags: .net, wpf, flowdocument, tableofcontents

I have created a flow document. In case the document is printed or saved to a file I would like to add a TOC to the start of the document.

What is the correct way of creating a TOC in a flowdocument? Can it be created automatically or should I add the TOC as the last thing looping through all the Paragraphs/Sections and manually add them to a table? If the manual creation is the way to go the next question that appears is how to determine the page number a Paragraph/Section is located on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to do this automatically. But the following works:

1. Reserve a page for the TOC
2. Build the remaining document
3. Insert the TOC on the reserved page and loop through the remaining sections and generate the TOC row by row. Page numbers of the sections are found using the `DynamicDocumentPaginator`

Note: If the TOC will span multiple pages more than one iteration is needed.

Comment: Great - but do you have a more detailed example? Maybe Code? Is there an event that I've register to to add the page? It must be during printing because it needs to fit to the printing page size and not to the screen size.